# Flexbox - how to create this layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Am trying to create the below layout in Flexbox, but am struggling.

[image: flexbox]

The green area takes up 20% of the page (horizontally), and the right two areas take up the remaining 80%. I'm thinking that it's best to have these as three separate containers in flexbox, as there will be lots of content that will need spacing inside each container.

Could anybody show me how this is made in flexbot? I just need the css for each container.

Comment: Can you include what you had tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using **CSS Flexbox** you can divide your layout into 2 parts (`.left` & `.right` where both are `20%` and `80%` respectively), like:

```
.child.left {
  flex: 20;
  background: green;
}

.child.right {
  flex: 80;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

And inside the `.right` child again divide the layout into 2 parts (make sure you should use `flex-direction: column` so that you can have a `top` `bottom` layout) and then divide the layout into 2 parts again with `20%` & `80%` respectively, like:

```
.child.right .top {
  flex: 20;
  background: red;
}

.child.right .bottom {
  flex: 80;
  background: blue;
}
```

**Have a look at the working snippet below:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.child.left {
  flex: 20;
  background: green;
}

.child.right {
  flex: 80;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child.right .top {
  flex: 20;
  background: red;
}

.child.right .bottom {
  flex: 80;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child left"></div>
  <div class="child right">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Though I don't understand why the child.right is set to 80 then also to 20, why is that?

Comment: @LGSon Yes. I agree with you. Just because of time constraint. Although I've updated my answer. You can have a look. Thanks!

Comment: Well, next time, if you have not time enough to post a proper answer, the don't until you have.

Comment: I will make sure @LGSon.